# EKCalendar allowsContentModifications

Tags: ios, objective-c

How does this property works? Seems that it is read-only but I'd like to set it. I need to create a calendar with events which are not editable? That would be the right way?

Comment: Did you find any way to make it work?

Comment: Nope. Seems that there is no way to do it.

Comment: `EKCalendar` of type `EKCalendarTypeSubscription` would have read-only events. But, I am not sure whether we can create such calendar programmatically (using APIs as of today, i.e. iOS 7).